# Eclipselink 2.7: using NULLS [FIRST|LAST] in Criteria API

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

i am trying to build a simple `ORDER BY hitCount DESC|ASC NULLS LAST` using the Eclipselink Criteria-Api. All available answers here fit the Hibernate-Implementation or NULLS LAST in JPQL. Since "NULLS LAST" works when specifying it in the JPQL-String, i really need the Criteria-solution, because this query is "very dynamic".

I found the class OrderByItem which has related constants, but i can't figure out how this class may be used:

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/parser/OrderByItem.html

```
Root<Product> p = query.from(Product.class);
Path<Long> hitCount= p.<Long>get("hitCount");

//...

Order oder = getSortDirection() == 0 ? builder.asc(hitCount) : builder.desc(hitCount);  
query.orderBy(order); //NULLS LAST ?

//
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Criteria API is a FIXED API. And there is no support for "NULLS" in the JPA standard, so you can't get access to it in Criteria. You would have to have a vendor extension to do that; I know that DataNucleus supports one by taking the JPA API jar and adding methods https://github.com/datanucleus/javax.persistence/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/persistence/criteria/Order.java#L35  but no idea if EclipseLink does

Comment: okay, it seems that this is sadly not available, at least i can't find anything about it in the extension reference:www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/jpa/extensions/annotations_ref.htm